# Any alternate proof for $2^n>n$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

The normal approach for these kinds of problem is to use the mathematical induction and prove that $2^n>n$ for any natural number $n$

**Case 1:** $(n=1)$

$2^1=2>1$, thus the formula holds for $n=1$

**Case 2:** (let us assume that this statement holds for any arbitrary natural number $m$)

That implies $2^m>m$ for some natural number $m$.

Then,
$2^{m+1}=2^m \cdot 2>m \cdot 2 \geq m+1$

Thus as the statement holds for an arbitrary natural number $m$ implies that it holds for $m+1$ and thus by mathematical induction, it is proved that $2^n>n$ for any natural number $n$.

Is there any other ways to prove this problem?
I tried proving this by contradiction taking initially $2^n \leq n$, but couldn't go much far.

Any help or idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There’s a very simple calculus proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a combinatoric argument, $2^n$ is the number of subsets of a set with $n$ elements which is always greater than the number of elements.

Refer to the related

- [The total number of subsets is $2^n$ for $n$ elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3068013/505767)

---

As an alternative, by derivative, let define

$$f(x)=2^x-x  \implies f'(x) =2^x \log 2-1$$

with $f(1)=1$ and $f'(1)>0$ therefore $\forall x\ge 1$

$$2^x-x \ge 0 \iff 2^x\ge x$$

Comment: Now you just have to prove that $2^x\log 2 - 1 >0$ for $x\geq 1$

Comment: @MPW Yes of course! I make that point more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We have $|\mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n \})| = 2^n$ and $|\{1,\dots, n\}| = n$ and there is an obvious non-surjective injection $$\{1, \dots, n \} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n \}).$$

**Edit:** Alternatively, $$2^n = (1+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \geq \sum_{k=0}^n 1 = n+1.$$ Note that in its spirit, this is not really a different proof. The binomial formula in this case is the same thing as counting subsets of a set.

A quick comment: Heuristically, because this inequality is so weak, there will be plenty of ad hoc arguments.

Comment: What is the obvious injection you have in mind? $x\mapsto \{x\}$? Note also you must prove that there is no surjection $\{1,\ldots n\} \to \mathscr{P}(\{1,\ldots,n\}$ as OP requires "$>$" and not just "$\geq$". Still, this is a nice idea, +1 for your answer

Comment: @MPW Yes. (I agree that it is not canonical.)

Comment: @MPW Ok, you're right. The obvious map does not hit $\emptyset$, so we're good. :)

Comment: Excellent, that's even nicer than what I was thinking! Clever you!

Comment: @MPW Thank you. :-) Looking at my edit, $\emptyset$ corresponds to $\binom{n}{0}$ in that argument.

Comment: Quite so ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

$$n=\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n\ \text{terms}}$$
$$2^n=\underbrace{2+2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^{n-1}}_{n\ \text{terms}}$$
$2^n>n$ follows from the fact that $2^i>1$ for $i\ge1$.